# How do gravitational waves and black holes interact?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, gravitational-waves

Following the first detection of gravitational waves yesterday (11 Feb. 2016) by LIGO, I have a couple of questions about how gravitational waves and black holes interact.

Assume that there is a black-hole in the path of a gravitational wave. What would happen? Would the gravitational wave even "notice" the black-hole?

Can gravitational waves be produced from the "inside" of a black-hole?

Comment: nothing can leave from inside a black hole.  These waves travel at c, while the space flow at c toward the BH.

Comment: Yes that is what I figured, but I wanted a definitive answer. Thank you.